# About gitlab CI runners

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to gitlab CI and I am fascinated with it. I managed already to get the pipelines working even using docker containers, so I am familiar with the flow for setting jobs and artifacts. I just wish now to understand how this works. My questions are about the following:

**Runners**

Where is actually everything happening? I mean, which computer is running my builds and executables? I understand that Gitlab has its own shared runners that are available to the users, does this mean that if a shared runner grabs my jobs, is it going to run wherever those runners are hosted? If I register my own runner in my laptop, and use that specific runner, my builds and binaries will be run in my computer?

**Artifacts**

In order to run/test code, we need the binaries, which from the build stage they are grabbed as artifacts. For the build part if I use cmake, for example, in the script part of the CI.yml file I create a build directory and call cmake .. and so on. Once my job is succesful, if I want the binary i have to go in gitlab and retrieve it myself. So my question is, where is everything saved? I notice that the runner, withing my project,  creates something like refs/pipeline/, but where is this actually? how could I get those files and new directories in my laptop

**Working space**
Pretty much, where is everything happening? the runners, the execution, the artifacts?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything that happens in each job/step in a pipeline happens on the runner host itself, and depends on the executor you're using (`shell`, `docker`, etc.), or on the Gitlab server directly.

If you're using gitlab.com, they have a number of shared runners that the Gitlab team maintains and you can use for your project(s), but as they are shared with everyone on gitlab.com, it can be some time before your jobs are run. However, no matter if you self host or use gitlab.com, you can create your own runners specific for your project(s).

If you're using the `shell` executor, while the job is running you could see the files on the filesystem somewhere, but they are cleaned up after that job finishes. It's not really intended for you to access the filesystem while the job is running. That's what the job script is for.

If you're using the `docker` executor, the `gitlab-runner` service will start a docker instance from the image you specify in `.gitlab-ci.yml` (or use the default that is configurable). Then the job is run inside that docker instance, and it's deleted immediately after the job finishes.

You can add your own runners anywhere -- AWS, spare machine lying around, even your laptop, and jobs would be picked up by any of them. You can also turn off shared runners and force it to be run on one of your runners if needed.

In cases where you need an artifact after a build/preparatory step, it's created on the runner as part of the job as above, but then the runner automatically uploads the artifact to the gitlab server (or another service that implements the S3 protocol like AWS S3 or [Minio](https://github.com/minio/minio)). Unless you're using S3/minio, it will only be accessible through the gitlab UI interface, or through the API. In the UI however, it will show up on any related MR's, and also the Pipeline page, so it's fairly accessible.